# Align the row values in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, gridview

I need to right align the values in a column of my gridview in asp.net 3.5
How can I do that?

```
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResults" runat="server" 
                                onpageindexchanging="gvSearchResults_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                CssClass="Grid" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" ForeColor="#333333" 
                                GridLines="None" Width="99%" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small">
                            <Columns>
                            <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Vendor Number" DataNavigateUrlFields="RecID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Apps/DataForms/Processor/ProcPanel.aspx?RecID={0}" DataTextField="VendorNum">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:HyperLinkField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorName" HeaderText="Vendor Name" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNum" HeaderText="Invoice Number" HtmlEncode="False"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceTot" HeaderText="Invoice Total" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="${0:0,0.00}"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Invoice Date"  HtmlEncode="False"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceApprover" HeaderText="Invoice Approver"  HtmlEncode="False"></asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333"/>
                                <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" />
                                <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader"  />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: figured it out. There was a CSS class that was overrighting part of my stuff;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need to use the RowStyle:

```
<asp:GridView>
   <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:GridView>
```

You can find some more detail information on RowStyle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx).

Comment: hmm that's weird, can you post a snippet of your code that shows what you're doing?

Comment: The RowStyle in your snippet doesn't have the HorizontalAlign in it.  Did you remove it when it didn't work or something?

Comment: I removed it after it didn't work. But the actual culprit was CssClass="Grid". This was overwriting my alignment.

Answer (score 10):

```
 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

You might also use `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"`

OR

```
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

Alternatively, create a CSS class with the `text-align` value to `right`. You can then set the `CssClass` property of the item to the class.