# Make of the Gridview Column Center and Right Align (MiddleRight)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, alignment

I need to align the values inside the Grid View to to Center and Right. Because I need to align Currency.

And other Columns need to be aligned Center and Left.

Can you Help me doing This??

I'm currently Doing This.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>Rs.<%# Eval("Payable_Bill_Amount","{0:n}")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This Aligns the Content to totally Right.
I need to align the Content to Right But Also to Center Like Calculations We Do

Ex:

```
 Required          Current

|    10.00  |   |     10.00|

|   110.00  |   |    110.00| 

|  1210.00  |   |   1210.00|
----------
```

Comment: maybe this post will be usefull for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085687/align-the-row-values-in-a-gridview

Comment: Check this for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085687/align-the-row-values-in-a-gridview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about aligning them to the right using

```
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
```

and then using CSS padding to add some space around the edge of the value in the cell?

Comment: I feel This as a best available alternative.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the answer if you feel it is so?

Answer (score 4):

Above accepted answer did not work for me. Although i did not try it in code as per above answer, i tried using the equivalent in the aspx page (which did not work).

```
<asp:BoundField etc>
  <ItemStyle etc />
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

What worked for me was

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="colHeader-RightAlign" />
```

and created a style within the `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .colHeader-RightAlign {
        text-align:right !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

This is what you need.

```
 GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
 GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
```

This should work.

Comment: It says `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultCellStyle' and no extension method 'DefaultCellStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
It also Says `DataGridViewContentAlignment Doesnot Exist in the Current Context`. Is there any name space which has to be added?

Comment: I think your using a  slightly different control.. Try, HorizontalAlign instead.

Comment: What different Contol? I've asked for GridView What Control you are using?? . Horizontal Align has Either `Center` or `Right` but not `MiddleRight`. What should I do?

Comment: See my EDIT. You have to assign the X & Y seperatley

Comment: The Content is being aligned to Right

Comment: Sorry, then change it to Left... HorizontalAlign.Left

Comment: I didn't mean to change it to left. I'm telling that the content is totally aligning to Right. I needed the content aligned to Right and To Center. If confused Please see the Question once Again.

Comment: Did you set the Vertical to middle?

Comment: Sir I don't need to align the content vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for perticuler column alignment

```
protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        // Set the alignment of cells containing numeric data.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Cells[6].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
```

Comment: HeaderStyle is used for grid header style and alignment, RowStyle is used for grid header style and alignment